# Eloquent: Scope for getting related models?

Tags: scope, eloquent

I have 3 models: User, Project, Task

Each user has many projects, each project has many tasks.

I want to do something like:

`$user->projects()->tasks()` to get the tasks of the projects of a user. `projects()` is a `hasMany()` relation and I believe `tasks()` should be a Scope, but have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose you have 3 models defined in this way:

**User**

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Project');
    }
}
```

**Project**

```
class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Task');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

**Task**

```
class Task extends Eloquent
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }
}
```

I believe this would be enough to query all the user projects and tasks.

If you already have an instance of User class you can just load the required relations:

```
$user->load('projects.tasks');
dd($user);
```

Having `belongsTo` relations defined allows you to query all the tasks with projects and users they belong to:

```
Task::with('project.user')->get();
```

I am not sure about getting just a list of tasks. This is the first solution that comes to my mind:

```
$tasks = Task::whereHas('project', function($query) use ($user){
    $query->whereHas('user', function($query) use ($user){
        $query->where('id', $user->id);
    });
})->get()
```

I believe there are other ways to achieve it using query builder and `join()` method.